# YouTube API Callback in IE7 and IE8

Tags: javascript, api, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

I'm having difficult getting the API to work in IE7 and IE8. Need simple pause / stop detection.

Even this demo page has IE8 errors and the callback events fail:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube_player_demo

Anyone has a work around for this?

Using this which works for the other browsers:

```
player = new YT.Player('youTubePlayer' + i, {
    height: height,
    width: width,
    videoId: getYouTubeID(src),
    enablejsapi : 1,
    events: {
        'onReady': onPlayerReady,
        'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange,
    },
    playerVars: {
        controls: 1,
        showinfo: 0 ,
        modestbranding: 1,
        wmode: "opaque"
    }
});
```

and

```
function onPlayerStateChange(evt) {
    if (evt.data == YT.PlayerState.PAUSED) {
    }
    if (evt.data == YT.PlayerState.ENDED) {
    }
    if (evt.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING) {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Youtube Iframe API is not compatible with IE7 because that browser doesn't support the `postMessage` function. You're left with using an AS3 embed, although I don't know that I'd put a lot of eggs in that basket, either ... given that Google commits to supporting only the latest two versions of the browser (which technically would be IE9 and 10, although it'll be interesting to see what happens with IE8 as you have Windows XP reaching EOL soon but Windows 8 being quite slow to be adopted), issues like this will continue to crop up as the technology and APIs evolve.

Generally, IE8 works fine right now as long as you're in standards mode; the demo page isn't throwing any errors for me (but is when I switch into compatibility or quirks mode). Are you getting any errors in the developer tools console? (that is, what do you mean by the callbacks fail?)

Comment: I can set a timeout and call the callback function details manually for IE8 once the library is loaded (since the library callback fails), this solves the IE8 issue.